# UIView animation lags on device

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation, lag

I'm using animation in my app and get confused, because animation is lagging on device, on simulator  everything seems OK. First I tried to use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
```

And before commit animation there were something like ~30 lines of code with "if" blocks so I thought this might cause the problem, but then I start to use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                             animations:^{
                                 mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                 buttonsView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 68);
                                 radioBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50);
                                 vk_controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440);
                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 button.isHiddenDown = YES;
                             }];
```

in terms of "if" blocks, but lags seems to stay. When I press button there is delay ~0.5-1 sec (why?) and then animation starts. But when I'm on table view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                             animations:^{
                                 mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                 buttonsView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 68);
                                 radioBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50);
                                 goha_news_controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                 goha_news_controller.feed_table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                 if(goha_news_controller.backgroundView)
                                 {
                                     goha_news_controller.backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                     goha_news_controller.newsDetailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
                                 }

                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 button.isHiddenDown = YES;
                             }];
```

in addition to the unexpected delay before the animation, there is harshness animation with bursts.
Can anyone explain why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you launch multiple animation at the same time ? And by multiple animation I mean multiple [UIView animate...] in the same method ?

Comment: No, only 1 animation block at the same time

Comment: I picked up someones code that did have multiple. Why is this bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible cause. Are you using shadows in any of the on-screen views or layers? iOS does not handle animating with shadows very well at all.

Comment: Yes, in table view there are shadows on image view layers. Do I have to remove it? And when I commit animation on view without shadows, there is no harshness moving, but still have delay ~0.5-0.8 sec between button pressed and animation

Comment: Oh wait, I use shadows for upper and lower bar, that must stay for every view, have to check it as cause of the problem

Comment: Yes, you were right, everything seems OK as performance, but ugly as design ;] There is no high performance alternatives to make shadows? Or this part must be created by designers?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the simulator to gauge performance. It has completely different (not just better or worse) performance characteristics than a device (and the devices also differ from generation to generation).

If statements are not causing significant delay; they are very cheap.

Your performance problems probably lie elsewhere. I can't see anything in the code you've shown us that looks like an obvious performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you resize images in controls while animation, this can cause lags, because image resizing is a very expensive process for CPU. You should make thumbnails of images before you run animation and change images.

Also, try to use Begin animations - commit animations instead of animating using blocks.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
// Here some more animation settings
// Here your animations 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I agree with your post about resizing images. However, why use beginAnimations:context: / commitAnimations? The new block-based animations work quite well in my experience, and are generally cleaner and easier to use. Also, Apple discourages use of the older style on iOS 4.0 and later

Comment: @DuncanC I completely agree, block animations are so much cleaner to work with and the completion blocks are way easier than creating a new method every time to use setAnimationDidStopSelector:@(SEL)

Comment: I used begin animations before, but I decided to replace it for 5 animation blocks (for each view controller) to avoid many frame resizings in 1 animation, but it didn't help at all. I don't resize exactly images, i resize views, table views and commit tranlations to upper and lower bar