# What can cause segmented Picker controls to "pop" rather than slide to the new selection, only on actual device?

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

My project has several Picker controls with `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())`. *Something* in the project (or, perhaps, on my iPad) has evidently changed, and now all of the pickers "pop" when selected, rather than the selection highlight sliding to the new selection -- ***but only on the actual device***.  In the simulator, the selection slides as expected.  Even a plain vanilla picker with code straight out of [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-segmented-control-and-read-values-from-it) exhibits this behavior on my device, so it seems that the issue is somewhere that has global effect, rather than in the code for an individual picker itself.  (That "vanilla" code, along with all my other Picker controls, look normal in the Simulator.)

Other UI elements animate normally on the device, so it isn't a blanket "turn off all animations" setting, but the various segmented pickers are **all** affected, even though they reside in different parts of the project. (And, yes, the project is way, *way* too big to post all of the code -- but "the code" works as expected in the simulator.)

**What are the sorts of things -- in a project or in a device's settings -- that can globally cause all segmented Pickers in a project to stop animating (though only on the device itself)?**

What I'm seeing on the iPad:

[image: selection snaps to the new choice]

What I'm seeing on the Simulator (i.e. what I expect to see):

[image: selection SLIDES to the new choice]

I recognized the simulator vs device distinction when I created a Simulator to exactly duplicate my iPad (Air gen 3, iOS 14.2), and the simulator shows the picker sliding (i.e. the bottom screen capture).  But the device shows it popping (the top screencap).  This behavior persists after deleting the app on the iPad, rebooting the iPad, and installing the app again.  So perhaps the 'guilty' setting is on the device rather than in the project???

**What settings, in the project or the device, could cause this change in behavior?**

Possibly related:

- [Broken animations in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951013/ios-14-broken-animations)
- Not SwiftUI, but device vs simulator [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595979/uiview-animation-lags-on-device)
- Example of "[OK on simulator, not OK on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373759/swiftui-contextmenu-on-lazyvgrid-cell-causing-animation-crash-when-map-present)" (though with different specific things going on)
- Another "[ran on simulator, not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63449700/7106170)" issue... does the Picker use the same problematic Spring animation???

(( And yes, there are plenty of cases where the simulator performs poorly & the device performs well... that's understandable.  This case is one where things are the other way around: what works on the simulator does NOT work as advertised on the device. ))

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @pawello2222. The link in the post is the code (one example of the code) that generates this behavior.  As to what will reproduce on another machine, I have no idea (thus the question).  What I'm seeing now doesn't reproduce what the exact same code did a few days ago.  Thus the question, what SORTS OF THINGS can lead to this behavior... I get it that pointing to 'line 17' in the code isn't going to happen.

Comment: I don't see any *popping* when running the code from the link above. Using Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3. Maybe you can add how it *looks* for you?

Comment: @pawello2222. Added a screencap of a picker.  In the past, this didn't pop like this, it slid.  As the example code does.  But ALL the pickers in the app, now, are doing like the one in the screencap -- not sliding.

Comment: And, added a 2nd screencap, recorded from the simulator.  Which behaves as expected.  So maybe some setting on the iPad itself is doing things with the animation?  Both the simulator + the iPad are iOS 14.2, same 3rd gen iPad Air.

Comment: I understand that you're asking *in general* but I don't think this is something which can be debugged without code. Especially if you're the only one able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @pawello2222. Since the simulator is displaying the Picker one way (the expected "sliding" behavior) and the iPad is displaying it the other (where the selection "pops" rather than slides), I'm questioning if it may be a setting (in XCode? on the iPad) rather than in the code for the app itself. After all, "the code" produces the expected result in the simulator!  So... what settings would cause the animation ***on the iPad*** to be different from what's in the simulator? I'll edit the question to emphasize that distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the **Reduce Motion** setting on your physical device. This can be found under Settings -> Accessibility -> Motion.

When reduced motion is **disabled**, the segmented picker has a slide animation.

When reduced motion is **enabled**, the segmented picker does not have the slide animation.